# C++ templated constructors: Do they prevent certain types from being inferred?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

If I have code like

```
struct Foo
{
    template<class T>
    Foo(T arg) { }
};
```

does that prevent `T` from ever being `const`, `volatile`, or a reference?

Similarly, if I have

```
struct Bar
{
    template<class T>
    Bar(T const volatile &arg) { }
};
```

does that mean `T` will never be `const`, `volatile`, or a reference?

Essentially, does that mean that constructor template parameters *must* be inferred, i.e. cannot be specified to be anything other than the inferred values?

Comment: @n.m.: Interesting, why is (1) no? (What's the counterexample?)

Comment: Um, actually this is wrong. (1) seems to be "yes" too, I'll dig a reference in a moment.

Comment: Here: "If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.". -- 14.8.2.1/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you cannot explicitly specify template arguments for a constructor template when you call it.

Because you never call it directly, but always implicitly through a cast or declaration.

You can specify them only when explicitly specializing or instantiating. That's not really useful, but possible

```
// explicit instantiation
template Bar::Bar<const int>(const int);
```

Comment: +1 interesting... so specializing `Bar::Bar` like this is completely useless, since it can't be `const int` anyway?

Comment: yes :) at least if you come up with a way that makes it useful, you will be my man

Comment: @Mehrdad well, you might give `T` a default template argument that is `const` and then you can call the constructor with `T` ending up as `const` :)